# Syntax highlighting for ksh

Tags: visual-studio-code

Syntax highlighting does not work with ksh.  It works with sh and bash just fine.  Any idea how to get this working or if it'll get supported in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can associate `Shell Script` with the `.ksh` file ending like this:

[image]

This will add the following to your `settings.json`:

```json
"files.associations": {
    "*.ksh": "shellscript"
}
```